# Premake equivalent of CMake's fetchContent

Tags: cmake, dependency-management, premake, fetchcontent

Is there an equivalent for CMake's [`fetchContent`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) for dependency management in Premake?
I know I can use Premake to generate a CMake project which calls `fetchContent` for automatically downloading dependencies from the web, but is there a more portable or streamlined way to do this using just Premake?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want, but premake uses lua, so you can call directly lua functions, such as `os.execute("git checkout ..")`, there is also [`http.download`](https://premake.github.io/docs/http.download). For msvc, premake integrates [`nuget`](https://premake.github.io/docs/nuget/).

Comment: @Jarod42 Basically downloading and linking external dependencies from online repositories automatically. Just like `fetchContent` does.

Comment: So download can be done with git(or other csv) or `http.download`. if those external projects use premake as buildsytem, there is [`include`](https://premake.github.io/docs/include)/[`includeexternal`](https://premake.github.io/docs/includeexternal/) possibility. [`externalproject`](https://premake.github.io/docs/externalproject) if they provide already visual solution. if they provide Makefile, you might create project to wrap it.